# HttpListener request output in c#

Tags: c#

Is there any way to get the httplistener to write the client request to the console?

I would like to capture what the user is requesting from the server, for instance if the client goes to http://server/request/4 I would like to capture the "/request/4" part.

I am using this example on MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well yes - when you get the request with `GetContext()` or the async equivalent, just print out `context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath`. Have you tried that already? if so, what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you have mentioned, you can use the RawUrl of the request object to print the current url that the client requested

```
// Note: The GetContext method blocks while waiting for a request. 
HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

Console.WriteLine("URL: {0}", request.Url.OriginalString);
Console.WriteLine("Raw URL: {0}", request.RawUrl);
Console.WriteLine("Query: {0}", request.QueryString);
// Obtain a response object.
HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
```

Note: The code is a copy paste of the example in the MSDN help. Please dont complain.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I couldn't find the obvious answer I guess. In any case, you solved it for me.